# How to fetch Background colour of the UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I am developing one iPad application using story board. In my application I have one `UITableView` and one `UICollectionView`. In `UICollectionView` the `UICollectionViewCell` contains one `UIImage` and `UIButton`. I am setting `backgroundColor` for the `UIImageView` using code based on the color coming from web api. I need to fetch the back ground color of the `UIImageView`. When I click the `UIButton` in the coresponding cell.

My question is: Is it possible to fetch the background color of the `UIImageView`?

Comment: Is it sufficent to get the color of one (any) pixel from an UIImage view?

Comment: you didn't try imageView.backgroundColor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but you can do something like:

```
UIColor *clr=self.imageView.backgroundColor;
```

It will return a colour. try using it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `backgroundColor` property of the `UIImageView` to get the color.